# Stop TableView Moving Top From Bottom

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, scrollview

I have three tabs in one view controller. I have used `UIScrollView` to scroll pages (ViewControllers). In the first Tab I have a `UITableView` and when I scroll to the Bottom of it (Very last index or object), the `UITableView` moves up completely. I tried this

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let  height = scrollView.frame.size.height
    let contentYoffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let distanceFromBottom = scrollView.contentSize.height - contentYoffset
    if distanceFromBottom < height {
        print(" you reached end of the table")

        if self.tableView.contentSize.height > self.tableView.frame.size.height {
            let  offset = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.frame.size.height))
            self.tableView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

It's not working. Can any one tell me how to fix this issue?

Thanks For help in advance

Comment: please put some code of this

Comment: if i write this in viewdidload its moving  very bottom on loading page if self.tableView.contentSize.height > self.tableView.frame.size.height {
            let  offset = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.frame.size.height))
            self.tableView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: true)
        }

Comment: when you reach at last index just call scrollToRowAtIndexPath method for this and pass 0 as index. It will solve your problem

Comment: where should i write and can u show sample line how to write

Comment: @IOS_PROGRAMMER Why does not you are using `UITableViewScrollPositionBottom ` to scroll the `UITableView` to bottom.

Comment: can u tell me where to write in scrollview method???

Comment: @IOS_PROGRAMMER What actually you are doing, I am not getting your, so please describe your required output, post screenshots if it is possible.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy i am displaying few items in tableview and when scrolling to bottom again tableview is moving up am just making tableview to work normally  scrolling  and i have three tabs in VC i need horizontal swiping for viewcontrollers so i used scrollview and at first tab i have VC with tableview in this tableview am getting scrolling issue

Comment: Disable the vertical scrolling of scrollView

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132756/discussion-between-ios-programmer-and-the-dahiya-boy).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to table view scroll to bottom :

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.bottom, animated: true)
```

And remove scroll view delegate.

Comment: when ever you want to table scroll to bottom. Like view did load

Comment: indexPath will be last index of the table.

Comment: let indexPath = IndexPath(row: array.count-1, section: 0)